# Trying to set up django with uwsgi and nginx on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: django, nginx

Plain and simple, I can't seem to figure this out. I should be able to get to mysite's media folder and see a test image but something is wrong.

Here's my conf file:

```
# catalog_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    #server unix:///home/ec2-user/catalog/catalog.sock; # for a file socket
    server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen  8000;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name 54.xxx.xxx.xxx; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN -- xxx are numbers in the actual conf
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /home/ec2-user/catalog/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {

        alias /home/ec2-user/catalog/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/ec2-user/catalog/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

I get no love from the page when I go to 54.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000/media/test.jpg

Tailing the logs gives me this:

> 2016/03/17 16:04:24 [error] 13950#0: *2 open()
>   "/usr/share/nginx/html/media/poweredby.png" failed (2: No such file or
>   directory), client: 66.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: localhost, request: "GET
>   /media/poweredby.png HTTP/1.1", host: "54.xxx.xxx.xxx", referrer:
>   "http://54.xxx.xxx.xxx/media/"

Nginx knows where to look for my site_nginx.conf file ... I'm stumped.

Help?

--UPDATE--

the folder '/usr/share/nginx/html/media/' does not exist but '/usr/share/nginx/html/' does ... same goes for '/static/'

sudo /etc/init.d/nginx configtest returns 'ok' and 'successful'

Is there anything that should be in the nginx.conf file that I may be missing?

Would permission problems cause this sort of behavior? How should I check for, or address that?

--UPDATE 2--

Somehow, nginx is being prevented from creating the '/media' and '/static/' folders in '/usr/share/nginx/html'

I created the folder manually and it served up the image. I have an idea of what to do next.

--dumb update--

The ip address that was in the question earlier has been changed to prevent the guy (or girl) in Ukraine from having too much fun.

Comment: Your server_name is correct? Maybe the request don't match with your server block.

Comment: Looks like the tutorial from the uWSGI site, which I've gone through. Try: 1) deleting the `default` config in the `sites-enabled` directory. 2) Stoppping and restarting `nginx` (?).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that request might not be hitting this snippet of nginx configuration. A request to `/media/poweredby.png` should be going to `/home/ec2-user/catalog/media/poweredby.png`, not the default nginx location `/usr/share/nginx/html/media/poweredby.png`. Is it possible that you didn't include this particular config file in your root nginx.conf?

That would look something like this:

```
# nginx.conf

user nginx; 

http { 

# stuff would go here 

}

include /etc/nginx/catalog_nginx.conf;
```